# Edit HTML outside ng-view on route change

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angular-controller

I want to change some HTML in the navbar upon a route change, using the routing information. I can almost get it to work with the code below, but the data is not parsed as HTML when arriving in the DOM. I tried using the `$sce` service, but that didn't really get me anywhere.

If there are any other (better) ways of editing the HTML on route change, then please let me know.

**HTML**:

```
<nav>
  <div ng-controller="BrandCtrl">
    <div class="nav-brand">
      {{brand}}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div ng-view></div>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.controller("BrandCtrl", function($scope, $route) {
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() { 
    var html = $route.current.html;
    $scope.brand = html;
  });
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/next-page', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/next-page.html',
    controller: 'BrandCtrl',
    html: '<h3>New brand</h3>'
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a template? Please note that you have 2 different instances of `BrandCtrl` on that route ... one for outside `<ng-view>` and the other inside

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. So obviously this is not the way to go. Care to elaborate on what you mean by just using a template?

Comment: Same way you render everything else in angular using templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be changing the HTML via the 'views' in the routes.

```
 $stateProvider.state('app',{url: 'someurl',   
    views: {
      'topnav': { templateUrl: 'path/to/some/html',
            controller: 'navcontroller'},
      'mainContent': {templateUrl: 'path/to/some/other/html',
            controller: 'contentcontroller'}    } 
 });
```

In your HTML you would have multiple views:

```
 <div ui-view="topnav"></div>   
 <div ui-view="mainContent"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Scott. However, I don't see how I would change the html in the topnav based on view changes in the mainContent.

Comment: View changes in the main content should be as a result of a route change. A user clicks on something and the route changes. When the route changes both the main content and the top nav would change. You can also pass parameters to your views via the route. So if you need to key off of something more specific than just a route, you can pass that along to the 'topnav' view and then that view can act accordingly, perhaps 'showing' or 'hiding' something based on that parameter passed in. Take a look at the docs for ui.router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router